# react-native react-navigation undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.value.startsWith')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two screens in my App. On a Button press I am moving from one screen to another. I am sending a parameter for the 2nd screen to display.

```
<Button onPress={ () => navigate('PDF', {pdf: 'Day1.pdf'})} >
```

The render() code for the PDF screen is like so

```
 render() {
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   const pdf = navigation.getParam('pdf', './assets/Day1.pdf');
   const abpdf = "\'./assets/"+pdf+"\'";
//     const rpdf = require('./assets/Day1.pdf');
  const rpdf1 = require(abpdf);
   return <WebView
      source={rpdf1} />
}
```

I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.value.startsWith')`

If I uncomment the hardcoded `const rpdf = require('./assets/Day1.pdf')` and replace the source in the WebView with rpdf everything works as expected. When I console log `abpdf` I get the right value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's blowing up because you're including single quotes in your string.  Try `const abpdf = "./assets/" + pdf;`

Comment: Thanks @larz. That was what I first tried. `const spdf = "./assets/"+pdf; const rpdf2 = require(spdf);`. Still get the same error. It appears to be in the require statement.

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: I am using expo snack which probably uses webpack underneath. I have been able to reproduce this in  a [smaller example](https://snack.expo.io/@ssuresh/require-evaluation). The `render` function in the file `AssetExample.js` has a commented outline which when uncommented gives the same `undefined` problem. It appears to be how the argument of `require` is being evaluated.

Comment: Ah yeah, it's definitely a webpack issue then.  When it compiles, it doesn't calculate what that variable is before it runs all of the `require` statements, so a dynamic `require` doesn't work.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Thanks @larz. I will work on importing all the files I need and then refer to those symbolically then rather than having require evaluate the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have dynamic require, this is being told explicitly in the doc

Answer (score 0):

As @larz points out when using webpack underneath, the `require` statements cannot have dynamic arguments. The solution is to import the files and then refer them symbolically.

Another approach is to use `eval` and ensure that Webpack doesnt analyze the `require` statements.

```
const ass="../assets/expo.symbol.white.png";
const rass = eval(`require('${ass}');`);
```

See a [small working example](https://snack.expo.io/@ssuresh/require-evaluation). See the file `AssetExamples.js`